# Shold I assign static IPv6 address to Windows servers?

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2016

I am working on deploying IPv6 on our WAN/LAN, I am going to have a /56 to assign. I will be subnetting it to 3 /64 subnets to start. My question now is on the LAN side, do I manually assign IPv6 addresses like I am doing with IPv4 and configure the firewall accordingly with no NAT?

For example I have a web server say 192.168.1.200 on the LAN, it has a WAN of 100.200.200.200. Would I then just assign say 2001:1100:2112:8D::8 on the IPv6 side and open port 443 on the firewall to that address?

I ask because I know there are different IPv6 addresses and its supposed to be more dynamic?

Answer (score 5):

One of the things about IPv6 is that it's expected an interface may have more than one. My laptop currently has 4 right now, for instance. Certain devices, like user endpoints, are expected to regularly hop around inside their /64. Servers, though, aren't.

You can assign static addresses to server assets. They auto-assign themselves additional dynamic ones, that's OK. Since they'll be responding to requests, so long as the static address has the hole punched through the firewall it will continue to serve just fine. This also makes it very easy to go back to IP-based virtual hosts instead of name-based, if you're doing web-serving.

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and setup the static